# Consulta Mysql no me resulta php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy teniendo problemas, ya que no logro que mi query mysql funcione, lo que estoy intentando hacer es mostrar una lista con la entidad que publico un producto ej: una remera.

El tema es que yo tengo el producto en una tabla y la entidad (negocio) que lo publico en otra.
Cuando yo agrego un producto no solo se me agrega a la tabla productos sino que la tabla donde esta la entidad se le agrega el id del producto y el numero de la entidad.

este es mi codigo:

```
            $conexion = Propel::getConnection();
            $sql = 'SELECT id_entidad FROM t2_producto_entidad  ORDER BY id_entidad DESC';
            $prepare = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $prepare->execute();
            $this->resulset = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

De alguna forma tengo que asociar los productos a la entidad y que me muestre cuando yo hago la lista los productos con la entidad que lo publico.

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es hacer una sola consulta para unir ambas tablas, por ejemplo: `SELECT productos.*, entidad.* FROM productos JOIN entidad ON producto.entidad = entidad.id_entidad`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te arroja?